# Map a key from one table to a value in another table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

There are two tables with the following schemas:

```
root
 |-- USER_ID
 |-- FOOD_KEY_1
 |-- FOOD_KEY_2
 |-- FOOD_KEY_3
 |-- FOOD_KEY_4
 |-- FOOD_KEY_5
 |-- FOOD_KEY_6

root
 |-- FOOD_KEY
 |-- FOOD
```

I want to map each key from first table to its actual value in table 2.

I could do something like this:

```
table = table1.withColumn('FOOD_1', table1.join(table2, FOOD_KEY_1 
 == FOOD_KEY,'inner').withColumnRenamed('FOOD', 'FOOD_1'))
 .withColumn('FOOD_2', table1.join(table2, FOOD_KEY_2 
 == FOOD_KEY,'inner').withColumnRenamed('FOOD', 'FOOD_2'))
 .....
```

However this does not seem the most optimal. Any better suggestions would be apprecaited!

Comment: you want to get food from table2 to table one that matches the key and populate it in the respective column. is that correct?

Comment: yes. I want to map 6 keys to 6 real values.

Comment: is your code working? and can you provide sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions always helps to strip redundant code. I think below code should solve the purpose.

```
key_col_df1 = list(set(df1.columns) - {'USER_ID'})

def join_df(left_df, right_df, join_key_left, join_key_right):
    return out_df = left_df.join(right_df, col(join_key_left) == col(join_key_right), 'inner')

new_df = df1
for col in key_col_df1:
    new_df = join_df(new_df, df2, col, 'FOOD_KEY')
```

df1 is dataframe with all the columns and df2 being the dataframe with mapping.